# Is smack 4.2.0 Beta2 compatible with openfire 3.8.1?

Tags: java, openfire, smack

I am using Smack 4.2.0 Beta2 with an old version of Openfire 3.8.1. I am unable to create a chatroom.

Are these compatible?

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenFire 4.2 respond to chat room create with following code

```
status code="110" 
status code="100' 
status code="201"
```

OpenFire 3.8.1 respond only with

```
status code="201"
```

Smack 4.2.0.beta2 expecting status code 110, so Smack 4.2.beta2 can't create chatroom with OpenFire 3.8.1, I found were the issue is

```
Class: MultiUserChat

Method: private Presence enter(MucEnterConfiguration conf)
```

Line:

```
StanzaFilter responseFilter = new AndFilter(...), MUCUserStatusCodeFilter.STATUS_110_PRESENCE_TO_SELF);
```

Comment: I will create a ticket

Answer (score 0):

It's better to ensure that the both are the latest and stablest versions.

Maybe You can refer to the [official doc for Class MultiUserChat](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, smack should be compatible to Openfire of any version. Each version of Smack's changes can look [here](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/changelog.html). The Openfire's changes from one version to another version can be seen from [here](http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/changelog.html). Then we know that one version just has some improvements, fixes and new features, these don't influence the use of tools each other.